# CSS3 border radius and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using CSS3 border-radius styles in my webpage and I want it to be cross-browser compliant across major browsers including IE8.

Therefore, I am trying to use the border-radius.htc file to achieve this. Wherever in my css styles the border-radius is used, i have coded something like:

```
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px; 
    behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
```

Unfortunately, when I check the webpage in IE8, all the backgrounds that have border-radius behavior end up not showing at all.

The webpage is at http://www.domainandseo.com/portfolio/dominos/index.html

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Internet explorer versions earlier than 9 do not support this property. Check the [compatibility matrix](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html). If you want rounded corners in old browsers you have to achieve them through an container carrying the rounded border image.

Comment: yes, they do not support CSS3 properties. But there are certain scripts etc that manipulate earlier browsers to achieve the css3 effects. border-radius.htc is one such for the browser-radius property. But right now the border-radius.htc is not functioning properly for my webpage on IE8, and instead of showing border radius for the backgrounds, it ends up not showing the backgrounds at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't known which "border-radius.htc" file you're using, but if you're using something like [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com), it's [a known issue](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#z-index). From their page:

> The only way I know of to work around this is to either:
>
> - make the target element position:relative, or
> - make the ancestor element position:relative and give it a z-index.
>
> Both of these workarounds can have potential unwanted side-effects in terms of child element positioning and z-index stacking. PIE could easily force one or the other itself, but:
>
> - One or the other may be more appropriate depending on the particular situation, so the CSS author needs to be able to control which one gets chosen.
> - Forcing position:relative outside of the CSS would put IE out of sync with other browsers, leading to confusing inconsistencies.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off trying to use a JavaScript polyfill rather than trying to load an .htc file. One that comes to mind is Mike Alsup's Corner jQuery plugin, found at http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/. You could use conditional comments to only load it in IE 8 or earlier:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script src="path_to_your_scripts_folder/jquery.corner.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('your_selector_here').corner('corner_radius_in_pixels');
    });
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Note that if you're using another polyfill for box-shadows, they won't show up very pretty using this.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 PIE requires the path used to be relative to the HTML and not to the CSS which is different than say an image or @font-face font you're loading via CSS.  You might find it works best to place the absolute URL to your PIE.htc file in your CSS.

Answer (score -3):

Try this it will work:

```
#main{position:relative;}
```

mention this id only in IE specific stylesheets.